# Cucumber Feature redirection failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

im new with rails and cucumber and BDD in general
im trying to test my registration process using scenarios

this is my signup feature

```
    Feature: Signup
      As a guest
      I want to create an account
      so that i can use all site's services

      Scenario: User successfully register
        Given I am a guest
        And I am on the homepage
        When I register a valid account
        Then I should be on profile page
        #And I should see a welcome message
```

and this is step files

```
Given (/^I am a guest$/) do
  @user = nil
end

And (/^I am on the homepage$/) do
  visit root_path
end

When (/^I register a valid account$/) do
  register(FactoryBot.create(:user))
end

Then (/^I should be on profile page$/) do
  puts current_path
end



module LoginSteps
  def register(user)
    visit registrazione_path
    fill_in('user_username', with: user.username)
    fill_in('user_email', with: user.email)
    fill_in('user_password', with: user.password)
    fill_in('user_password_confirmation', with: user.password)
    fill_in('user_comune', with: user.comune)
    fill_in('flatpickr-input', with: user.data_nascita)
    click_button("Crea account")
  end
end


World(LoginSteps)
```

i put a "puts" on the 4th step to check in which page iam  after registration
the problem is that it redirect to /users when it should be on /users/id

the application is working fine but not the tests
any suggestion?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to debug this to see whats happening. I'd do the following.

1) Temporarily add the javascript tag to your scenario so it will run in a browser and then you can see what happens. (this is optional, but I find it very useful for debugging scenarios)

2) Debug just before you click the button so you can see if the fields for registering are filled in correctly

3) Debug in your registration controller so can examine the params hash.

Additionally you may want to debug what `FactoryBot.create(:user)` is doing. I think its possible that it isn't creating a password, as the password field in the User model is almost certainly a salted hash and not the plain text password.